# Inconsistencia en datos al momento de pasar desde un ResultSet a un Vector/ArrayList

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc

En primera instancia, hola a todos los lectores que lleguen a futuro. En segundo lugar (no por importancia), el contexto:

Estoy trabajando en unas modificaciones para un sistema de reportes montado en tomcat7(jdk1.8_211), y estoy teniendo problemas al momento de ejecutar varios reportes en simultaneo, me explico:
Cuando pido varios reportes en simultaneo funciona todo bien hasta que llega la función `llenarData(rs)` donde se supone debería de pasar el contenido de la query desde el ResultSet hasta una variable `Vector datos` (lo cual hace perfectamente cuando el reporte es solo uno),el problema en cuestión es: cuando pido varios reportes en simultaneo, en ocasiones (muy inconsistente) algunos de los reportes presentan una diferencia de filas entre el `Vector datos` y el `ResultSet rs` y cuando esto pasa, el reporte queda inútil.(ej. para un reporte de 4917 filas, el `Vector datos` acusa un numero distinto de filas, desde algunas menos, hasta miles extras).

```
public class Reportes{
    public static Vector datos = new Vector();
    public static Vector columnas = new Vector();

    public void llmarReporte(){
    
        //...
        Connection con = this.getConection();
        Resultset rs = this.getResulset(con, query);
        //...

        llenarData(rs);
        //...

    }
    public ResultSet getResulset(Connection con, String query){
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try{
            Locale.setDefault(new Locale("es","ES"));
            
            //CallableStatement e = con.prepareCall(query); // esto estaba originalmente en el codigo

            // desde aca -------> 
            Statement e = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPER_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            rs = e.executeQuery(query);
            
            rs.last();
            System.out.println("resulset.size:" + rs.getRow());
            rs.beforeFirst();
            // ------> hasta aca lo agregue yo, solo para saber el numero de filas del ResultSet, 
            // lo cual "arreglo" un error que mezclaba los reportes
        }catch(Exception exp2);
            //...
        }
        return rs;
    }

    public static void llenarData(Resultset rs){
        try{
            GetColumns(rs); //<--rellena Vector columnas
            while(rs.next()){
                Vector e = new Vector();
                for(int i = 0; i < columnas.size();i++){
                    e.addElement(rs.getString(i + 1));
                }
                datos.addElement(e);
            }
            rs.close();
        }catch(Exception exp1){
            // ...
        }finally{
            System.out.println("nuero de datos: "+datos.size());
        }
    }
    public static void GetColumns(ResultSet res) throws SQLEXception{
        try{
            ResulSetMetaData met = res.get.MetaData();
            columnas = new Vector():
            for (int i = 0; i < met.getColumnCount();i++){
                columnas.addElement(met.getColumnName(i + 1).toUpperCase());
            }
        }catch(Exception metaExc){
            // ..
        }
    }
}
```

Alguna idea de que puede ser la inconsistencia en el numero de filas dentro del `Vector datos` ??
PD: intente cambiar todos los Vectores por ArrayList, pero el error se repite exactamente igual.
PD: Gracias de antemano =)

Comment: ¿El código que adjuntas siquiera compila? ¿¿¿ `for(int = i;` ??? ¿¿`public class Reportes() {}`??  ¿Donde asignas los datos en `llenarData` al vector `datos`? ¿De dónde sale `numColumnas` en `llenarData`?

Comment: 1.- sorry meti mal el dedo en el for cuando escribi la pregunta
2 .- no entendi la pregunta
3.- Con el for se arma un vector con el contenido de la fila y se agrega al vector datos
4.- no pense que seria necesario explicitar donde, pero lo agrego al codigo ahora

Comment: desde la declaración de la clase la cosa pinta mal. ¿Que significan esos `()` en la declaración de la clase? ¿El IDE no te los señala? Por favor, inserta código que mínimo compile sin errores de sintaxis.

Comment: creo q ahora si quedo bien escrito =)

Comment: Perfecto, vamos mejorando algo. Lo otro que debes saber es que, los ciclos `for` de por si incrementan solos la variable `i` (bueno, no solos, ya se lo dijiste tú en la declaración cuando pusiste `i++`). No tienes tú que hacer `getColumnName(i+1)` ni `e.addElement(rs.getString(i + 1));`. Por favor, elimina el `+1` de ambas sentencias y prueba tu código.

Comment: Lo último, y no se si es tu objetivo porque desconozco el contexto en que llamas a esta clase. Es que nunca estás borrando los datos del reporte anterior. Cada vez que llamas a `llmarReporte`, los datos se siguen y se siguen y se siguen agregando al final de `datos`. Nunca borras el contenido de esa variable, por lo que puede que tal vez el primer reporte te "salga bien", pero el resto tendrá los datos de todos los anteriores. Es basicamente una caja en la que meto y meto y meto cosas y nunca saco.

Comment: Sin contar que la frase _"varios reportes en simultaneo"_ teniendo una sola variable **ESTÁTICA** para columnas y una sola variable **ESTÁTICA** para datos  no suena muy bien. ¿a qué te refieres exactamente con _simultáneo_? ¿Diferentes hilos?

Comment: intente quitando los ```+ 1``` , pero se cae al momento de llegar al ```getColumnName(i)``` . creo que tiene que ver con los indices de sql vs los de java

Comment: con "reportes en _simultaneo_" me refiero que múltiples consultas simultaneas a la webapp, con respecto a las variable **estática**, si te soy sincero, soy nuevo en esto y el código es un extracto del código original con el que funciona el server (mis modificaciones trabajan con el resultado de ```llenarData(rs);``` ), así q te mentiría si te digo que se a que te refieres, me puedes explicar porque no suena bien tener solo 2variables estáticas, una para los nombres de columnas y otra para los datos? (se trabajan por separado mas adelante en el código)